# Socket programming, C-java

Tags: java, c, sockets

Hey guys, i've been searching for some info on sockets programming for a few hours right now and still can't understand how to solve a problem i have.

I've been asked to do the following :

The server receives an UDP datagram at the port 8080, sent from a client, in the datagram the client sends an array of chars that represents a number(9090)
The server will create a new socket, establish a TCP connection with the client at the port 
9090.
Through the tcp connection, the server will read the a name, sent by the client.

We're asked to write a client able to do those tasks in C, the server is already done and is found in a .jar file

The program should run like this : ./client SERVER_NAME

and the server: java -jar server.jar

i got as far as this goes...with a think it covers the first part(sending the udp package) but not quite sure how to follow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define SERVERPORT "8080"    // the port users will be connecting to

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd;
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    int rv;
    int numbytes;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr,"usage: talker hostname\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;

    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(argv[1], SERVERPORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
    }

    // loop through all the results and make a socket
    for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
                p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
            perror("talker: socket");
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    if (p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "talker: failed to bind socket\n");
        return 2;
    }

    int num = 9090;
    num = htonl(num);
    if ((numbytes = sendto(sockfd, num, sizeof(num), 0,
             p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen)) == -1) {
        perror("talker: sendto");
        exit(1);
    }
```

Comment: What is the *specific* question here?

Comment: The client creates a connect to a server.  I suggest you work out which is the client and which is the server. I would also create a client and a server in Java as this will be faster to implement, and use that for testing.

Comment: in theory a should only do the C program, the server is already done in that jar file

Comment: So the question is; how to implement the listening socket to accept connections in C?  As UDP is a lossy protocol you may need to send the UDP packet more than once, after a suitable delay.

Comment: yeah i'm familiar with the theory of the protocols, but never really programmed anything like that, the question is:
How do i continue to program to do the tcp part?
and also if the code is ok so far

Answer (score 0):

Does the java server provide any feedback you can use to verify the your UDP thus far? If so, I would verify and proceed as follows..

Setup a separate socket to make the TCP connection. There are many resources on the Internet showing how to do that (Google 'c tcp client example'). Since UDP is an unreliable best-effort protocol you will want to have a method for retrying the connection. One solution might be to loop, sending the UDP datagram and trying the TCP connection on the other socket until the connection is made (or some other time limit or maximum retry limit is reached).

```
// setup TCP socket to connect to your chosen port 'num'...
if ((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0)
// handle error

struct sockaddr_in tcpServAddr;
memset(&tcpServAddr, 0, sizeof(tcpServAddr));
tcpServAddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
tcpServAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(<insert server ip here>);
tcpServAddr.sin_port        = htons(num);

const int iMaxTries = 10;
int iTryCount = 0;
bool bConnected = false;
while(!bConnected && (iTryCount < iMaxTries)) {
  // using your bock from above:
  if ((numbytes = sendto(sockfd, num, sizeof(num), 0,
             p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen)) == -1) {
        perror("talker: sendto"); // may want to output strerr(errno) for more information
        break; // something is wrong if we can't send UDP. bail and figure that out
  }

  ++iTryCount;

  // try the TCP connection on the target port
  if (connect(tcpSockFd, (struct sockaddr *) &tcpServAddr, sizeof(tcpServAddr)) == 0) {
    bConnected = true;
  } else {
    // report error
  }
}

if (bConnected) {
   // send(...) name on tcpSockFd
}
// cleanup sockets
```

None of the above is tested, but hopefully it gives you some general direction.

Comment: One strategy would be to alternate between sending the UDP packet and listening for the connection (with a timeout) on the TCP port.  When the connection request occurs, you stop sending the UDP packet and start dealing with the TCP socket.

Comment: It was my impression that the java server was both receiving the UDP packet, then 'listening' for the TCP connection on the specified port. In that case, there would be no listening in the client.

Comment: The server listens for a UDP packet which indicates what port the client has open for the server to connect over TCP. At least, that is how I read it.